# Run an onClick statement then an onSubmit statement

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, onsubmit

PHP:

```
echo '<form action="../apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="check" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$ID.'" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirmDelete();" "style="margin-right: 5px;" />';
echo '</form>';
```

I want to add an onSubmit statement that will reload the window (using "window.location.reload") once the onClick event has happened. If I add it to my code as is, only onSubmit runs.

```
function confirmDelete()
{
    var agree= false;
    var agree= confirm("confirm?");
    if (agree == true)
    {
        var result = new Array();
        result[0] = ('<?php     
        if (isset($_POST['check']))
        {
            if ($queryType == "apps")
            {                           
                (THIS INCLUDES PHP FILES TO BE RUN)
            }
        }
        ?>');
        result[1] = true;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like to reload the page if the user confirms. I feel like I have tried almost everything to have the onClick function run and then reload the page. Please help!

Comment: single quotes breaks try double quotes inside single one `$_POST["check"]`

Comment: The onClick function works perfectly fine.

Comment: you have defined result as array and then returning it..you should return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't return anything if the user confirms, then the submit method will go on. The submit will follow after that. You could as well swap this onClick function to the onSubmit of the form.

Comment: The weird thing is, I tried swapping the onClick to an onSubmit but it didn't work and I have no clue why. I'll try your suggestion though.